# Help evaluating a model in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am a newbie in R and I am trying to do my best to create my first model. I am working in a 2- classes random forest project and so far I have programmed the model as follows:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(2015)
RF.fit <- randomForest(as.factor(goodkit) ~ ., data=training1, importance=TRUE,ntree=2000)
varImpPlot(RF.fit)
Prediction <- predict(RF.fit, test)
```

So far everything seems to be ok with my code but I am not able to calculate neither the OOB nor the prediction porcentage (recall) to evaluate the model.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing?
Till here everything seems to fine with my code but I am not able to calculate the OOB and the prediction porcentage(recall) to evaluate the model.

Comment: To get OOB simply type:
    print(RF.fit)

Comment: changed the the object name to RF.fit as object named  RandomForest from randomForest function is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your question is better suited to stackoverflow, but I'll give you an answer since it is still related to statistics.
There exists a package ROCR that makes assessing classifiers simple by providing functions like oob, roc, lift curve etc. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

After training a random forest, I usually do the following:

```
#Train the classifier
rf.classifier <- (my_response ~., data=mydata, subset=train.indices)

#Obtain the OOB error rate and confusion matrix. 
print(rf.classifier)

#Determine which features were the best
importance(rf.classifier)
```

Between the OOB error rate, confusion matrix, and weights on your features, you should be able to get a sense of how well your model is doing and what's making it do well.